# How can I route vias to components?

Tags: pcb, rf, analog

I am trying to route a capacitor to the base of a transistor but when I try to route a resistor terminal to a via, KiCad doesn't permit me to connect the resistor to the via terminal directly.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the two components may have different net names in your schematic? If so, it won't allow you to connect them.  Fix that first, then you should be able to make the connection.

Comment: thank you. I changed and matched the net names and i was able to connect the vias to the base of the transistor.